# How to stop hatching. Link with the mother

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to make a simple model where the turtles move around the world and they reproduce only one time. So, if the model starts with 20 turtles, it has to stop when it reaches 40 (without telling it in the code). After hatching, the new turtles will link themselves with the mother. Here is the code.

```
breed [sons son]
sons-own [...]

to setup
  ca
  crt 20
  [while [any? other turtles-here]
    [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]]
  reset-ticks 
end

to go
  move
  reproduce
  tick
end

to move
  ask turtles [
  lt random 45
  rt random 45
  fd 0.5
  ]
end

to reproduce
  ask turtles [
    if count my-links = 0 [
      hatch-sons 1 [create-link-with myself]
      ]
    ]
end
```

The code here works perfectly but I'd like to know if there is some command like `stop` to make the hatching stop after 1 son. I tried with `stop` but the way I tried didn't seem to work.

Comment: what do you mean without telling it in the code? the normal way would be to do something like `if count turtles >= 40 [stop]` as the first line in the go procedure. The 40 can instead be a slider on the interface.

Comment: I mean that I don't want any other condition but hatching 1 son per agent. The total number of sons isn't relevant, what is relevant is the number of born sons per agent.

Comment: Since the initial turtles start with no links and form a link with a hatchling, simply testing for links (as you do) seems fine.  What need is it not meeting?

Comment: The testing is enough in this model but I want to implement it in a more complex one where there are too many turtles and links to have a simple upper limit to the hatching. Maybe I'm being nitpicky but It would be nice if there were some code to just tell the turtles "you hatch only once in your entire life".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to have your turtles only ever hatch one offspring is to simply create a `turtles-own` variable that you can use to keep track of whether a turtle has reproduced. Here is a very simple example:

```
turtles-own [ have-reproduced? ]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  crt 20 [
    set have-reproduced? false
    setxy random 30 - 15 random 30 - 15 
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    if have-reproduced? = false [
      hatch 1       
      set have-reproduced? true
    ]
    fd 1
  ]
end
```

In the above code, the `have-reproduced?` variable is initially `false` for all turtles. Once the turtle hatches an offspring, however, their `have-reproduced?` is set to `true`, so they will not hatch any offspring the next time the procedure is called (although their offspring will). Try running that code and including a monitor for `count turtles` on your interface, and you will see that the number of turtles increases by 20 every time `go` is called.

Answer (score 3):

The primitive `stop` is to exit a loop but that seems unnecessarily complicated since all you want to do is pull out the subset without sons and have them reproduce. Your existing code is fine with a little modification to make them directed links (otherwise the children will not reproduce as they have a link to their parent), but this may be clearer.

```
to reproduce
  ask turtles with [ count my-out-links = 0 ] [
    hatch-sons 1 [create-link-from myself]
  ]
end
```

note that I also changed the link creation to be directed.

Comment: Could you tell, for the two options (yours and Luke's) which one would be more CPU consuming in a bigger model? For this little one there's no problem but if I want to implement it into a big one...

Comment: There is an extension called profiler that is exactly for such a purpose